# Angular chartjs setting options

Tags: charts, angular-chart

I've been bumping my head against this all morning.

http://jsbin.com/cutumigexa/1/edit?html,js,output

I cannot seem to set the lineTension (also tried tension) property on the line chart,I always get the bezier default lines.I basically need spiked lines.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Silly me,needed this

$scope.datasetOverride = [{lineTension: 0.001}];